# Getting javahg 0.6-SNAPSHOT from Maven

Tags: javahg

I'm trying to get JavaHG 0.6 snapshot using the following Maven pom:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.aragost.javahg</groupId>
    <artifactId>javahg</artifactId>
    <version>0.6-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>sonatype-ossrh</id>
    <name>Sonatype Open Source Software Repository Hosting</name>
    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

This makes the build fail with the following error:

```
Could not find artifact com.aragost.javahg:javahg-parent:pom:0.6-SNAPSHOT in sonatype-ossrh (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/) -> [Help 1]
```

I think this is because 0.6-SNAPSHOT is not found in 
https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/aragost/javahg/javahg-parent/

Does anyone know how to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately recent builds aren't in maven currently. It is possible to build locally. 
This thread has some details: https://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/main/issue/424/plugin-readmemd-information-out-of-date

- Clone the JavaHg repositories, including `javahg-parent`
- Update to the `0.6` tag for each
- Invoke `mvn install` for `javahg-parent`, and then again for the other repositories